# RSpec Request spec setup issue

Tags: rspec, request, rspec-rails

I have the following spec:

```rb
it "allows a valid request" do
  user = create :user

  headers = {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{user.api_token}"}
  get "/api/v1/user", nil, headers
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

which should work, however, RSpec disagrees:

```
Failure/Error: get "/api/v1/user", nil, headers
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
```

Why does RSpec see a different signature for `get` to what is expected ([examples](https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/request-specs/request-spec/))

What's missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params and headers arguments are should be hash-style.

so your request-line should be like below.

```
get "/api/v1/user", params: nil, headers: headers
```

Or this also works.

```
get "/api/v1/user", headers: headers
```